# Routing to an aspx page on a project with webforms and MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've added MVC to an existing webforms project that I've been working on as I'm looking to slowly migrate the project, however, during the change over period I need to be able to access both, but have it default to the aspx pages.

When it comes to registering the routing, I currently have this in place:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapPageRoute("Backup", "{*anything}", "~/Default.aspx");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MVC", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = 1 }
        );
    }
```

However, when I have it setup like this, even if I put in a URL that I know refers to a controller/action combination (e.g. Test and Index from the last line of this), it still redirects the user to the Default.aspx page.

I've tried changing this over to the following:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MVC",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = 1 }
        );

        routes.MapPageRoute("Backup", "{*anything}", "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Here, the user can specify a page or specify a controller/action, but if they do not include any controller/aspx page, it defaults to the default MVC route, whereas I need it to default to the webform Default.aspx.

How would I get around the situation so that if no page/controller is specified, it directs to ~/Default.aspx, and if a controller is specified, it directs to that controller?

Comment: you can add a simple controller and then redirect it to your aspx page,or use this code on your global.ascx :  
  
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {  
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Home","Home/Index","~/Default.aspx");  
      
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried experimenting with your scenario where in i have an existing web forms application and have added mvc to it. Basically i have come across two solutions.

**First:** you can ignore adding `routes.MapPageRoute` to route config; this is what i have done

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

***Please notice*** that i have excluded value for controller in the defaults. Now even if there is a match and if there is not controller present by that name then the request will fall back to the regular ASP.Net pipeline looking for an aspx page. With this approach you could request urls like `http://localhost:62871/` or `http://localhost:62871/Home/Index` or `http://localhost:62871/Home/` or `http://localhost:62871/About.aspx`

**Second:**: In this approach you can create an *area* under *Areas* folder for your new MVC based work and leave the *RouteConfig* in `App_Start` to its default so that it looks like following.

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
        }
    }
```

And then in your Area registration class define route as in following example .

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, the first approach works perfectly and covers what I need for now, but I may start using the 2nd approach later down the line if I need to split things in such a manner. This is a huge help!